# Difficulty typing arguments for System.Linq.Enumerable.Select

Tags: c#, linq

I've been staring at this for awhile and not sure how to fix it.

All I'm trying to do is fill in the arptable description property where it matches the address in the device table. I am not trying to create another collection from the arptable.

**Error:**

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

**Here is the offending code:**

```
 IEnumerable<ARPTABLE> GetARPTable()
    {
        IpTable arp = new IpTable();
        IEnumerable<ARPTABLE> arptable = arp.GetArpTable();


        arptable.ToList().ForEach(i =>
        {
            DeviceTable.Where(j => j.PhysicalAddress == i.MAC)
                       .Select(y =>
                           {
                               i.Description = y.Model ?? y.DeviceName;
                           });

        });

        return arptable;

    }
```

where DeviceTable is

```
public ObservableCollection<Device> DeviceTable { get; set; }
```

Thanks for any help (or a better way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is having trouble because your lambda expression isn't written correctly and so it fails on type inference. Unfortunately, the whole construction of the method is broken and I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

But in terms of getting it to compile, your method should look more like this:

```
IEnumerable<ARPTABLE> GetARPTable()
{
    IpTable arp = new IpTable();
    IEnumerable<ARPTABLE> arptable = arp.GetArpTable();

    foreach (var i in arptable)
    {
        Device j = DeviceTable.FirstOrDefault(j => j.PhysicalAddress == i.MAC);

        if (j != null)
        {
            i.Description = j.Model ?? j.DeviceName;
        }
    }

    return arptable;
}
```

As a general note: do not use methods like `Select()` as a way to simply visit each element in the collection. The expression you give to the `Select()` method will not actually be evaluated unless you evaluate the `IEnumerable<T>` that was returned, which you did not in this case. And even if you do evaluate the `IEnumerable<T>`, it's an inefficient misuse of the method.

Also, while `List<T>.ForEach()` could be considered convenient by some, it is wasteful to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>` just for the purpose of calling that method. A regular foreach statement works fine and is more efficient.

Comment: "Error: Cannot modify members of 'i' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'" What to do?

Comment: Got it. Change ARPTABLE from struct to class. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is not ment to be used for filling in data. It's a query language and so the `Select` method returns a new sequence. Just do it with foreach. I would image it could look like this, although I'm not exactly sure if I got the logic right.

```
foreach(var table in arptable)
{
    var device = DeviceTable.SingleOrDefault(...);
    if (device != null)
    {
        table.Description = device.Model ?? device.DeviceName;
    }
}
```

As for your current form

```
arptable.ToList().ForEach(i =>
```

this is really not necessary, why cast the sequence to list if you don't have to? Just to use that `ForEach`? We can do better.

```
DeviceTable.Where(j => j.PhysicalAddress == i.MAC)
           .Select(y => i.Description = y.Model ?? y.DeviceName);
```

This returns a new sequence, which you are not storing in any local variable. LINQ queries should not have side effect, it's against the lambda calculus, the idea behind LINQ itself.

Comment: It is worth noting that `SingleOrDefault()` is a deviation from the original code, in that it will throw an exception if more than one element of the enumeration matches the predicate condition. The original code actually more closely matches `LastOrDefault()`. (But I figured there's no obvious reason to care the order based on the code given, so I used `FirstOrDefault()` instead because it does "early out").

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are absolutely right and I'm aware of that, but I think that's the desired logic, but I might be wrong. Maybe he wants to get more matching devices and somehow aggregate the final value for a description.

Comment: I agree it may well be the desired logic. Heck, personally I would've implemented the device table as a dictionary, enforcing the one-entry-per-MAC-address long before the code here would be executed. :) But in any case, from the code that was posted, it's clear that it's important to highlight anything that might be different from the original intent. My comment is for that purpose, not meant as a criticism of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

i like the other answers. if you still want to use `linq`, this is how you would:

```
IEnumerable<ARPTABLE> GetARPTable()
    {
        IpTable arp = new IpTable();
        IEnumerable<ARPTABLE> arptable = arp.GetArpTable();

        arptable = arptable.Select(i =>
        {
            Device device = DeviceTable.SingleOrDefault(j => j.PhysicalAddress == i.MAC);

            if (device != null)
            {
                i.Description = device.Model ?? device.DeviceName;
            }

            return i;
        });

        return arptable;

    }
```

Comment: You can write `DeviceTable.SingleOrDefault(j => j.PhysicalAddress == i.MAC);` instead of `DeviceTable.Where(j => j.PhysicalAddress == i.MAC).SingleOrDefault();`.